# jQuery datepicker display format

Tags: jquery, datepicker, format

I have MySQL table with date field (yy-mm-dd).

And I have form with datepicker that edits it and it works fine.

BUT at the frontend date is displayed as mm-dd-yy and that can be confusing.

I'd like field with datepicker to display value as mm-dd-yy, but the actual value should be of the old format (yy-mm-dd).

How to reach this?

Added: I know how to change format of date. I want **separate** displayed value and actual value. That's what it is all about.

Answer (score 16):

The jQuery UI Datepicker widget comes with `altField` and `altFormat` options that allow you to set a secondary (hidden if you want) form input to store the date in whatever format you want:

```
$( ".selector" ).datepicker({
    altField  : '#actualDate',
    altFormat : 'yy-mm-dd'
});
```

*Source: http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#option-altFormat*

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/MmKmq/

Comment: This is an awful hack by jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this jquery page, it will direct you to what you want:

http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Datepicker#option-dateFormat

as for processing it as yy-mm-dd you may have to do this through a method on your web page to rearrange the formatting.

Comment: thats what i meant by "you may have to do this through a method on your page....". what you could do is have a hidden text box that acts as the real value and the other text box is what the user sees. then you could save the hidden value?? just an idea...

Comment: That's too complex... My form is generated automatically and datepicker is attached automatically too. If I will have to make additional elements manually and make event processing manually and so on it will ruin all the flexibility. Is there really no way to make it with DP internal ways?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
<input type="text"   id="displayDate" />
<input type="hidden" id="submittedDate" />

<script type="text/javascript">

   $(document).ready(function() {

      $("#displayDate").datepicker({
         dateFormat: 'MM dd, yy', // this is the format of the date that will be shown
         onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
            var date  = new Date(dateText);
            $("#submittedDate").val(date.getTime()); // transform into what you want to submit here
         }
      });

   });

</script>
```